# I Thought That I Planted Basil Here

Tags: identification

[image]
I am new to gardening, so I was a little afraid to use this plant. I looked up pictures of Basil, and I don't see any that look like this.  The stems smell sweet. I live in Ohio. 
Thank you

Comment: If you didn't plant any other herbs, I wouldn't recommend eating this - its definitely not Cilantro (coriander) and I'm unconvinced its parsley... Either way, you're right - its definitely not Basil.  More likely to be a weed of some variety....

Comment: Thank you so much. No, I didn't plant any other herbs.  I will pull this up tomorrow. Next year, I will plant well marked herbs in a pot!

Comment: Bamboo is right. Do no use it. Parsley family has a lot of very poisonous plants. BTW it could be "wild" celery.

Comment: What about lovage? Does it smell like celery? Just so you know, if anyone thinks that's what it is I don't mind if someone else answers and says that's what it is (nor do I mind in other situations like this). I don't know what it is, but I thought there was a semblance, and maybe someone else would know.

Answer (score 1):

Since the leaves resemble celery and the stems and leaves smell sweet you very probably have Anis(e) (*Pimpinella anisum*). Flowers yellow in an umbel like wild carrot. The seeds are used in high quality liqueurs and sometimes in bread like carraway, perhaps. I don't think the leaves or other parts of the plant are commonly used, except in a medicinal context or for entertainment.

Comment: Now that's one smell that I would recognize. I love the smell of Anise. This is not that smell, but you have given me an idea for next year. Thank you